# Redirect folder, and sub folders, to a new folder (do not carry any sub folder info across)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm struggling to find a solution here.

I need (via htaccess):

```
www.domain.com/tag/
www.domain.com/tag/my-first-tag/
www.domain.com/tag/my-second-tag/
```

To ALL redirect to

```
www.domain.com/new-folder/
```

I do not want any information carried across like:

```
www.domain.com/new-folder/my-first-tag
```

I have tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tag[/]?$ /new-folder/
```

But this only redirects one url: /tag/ and no sub folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /tag/ /new-folder/
```

This will redirect all of your URLs ending with `/tag` or `-tag` to `/new-folder/`.

Comment: Sorry. Not all the tags will end -tag. That was, purely for an example. They will be random words after /tag/. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Waited until back in the office to try this. The solution was simple!

Comment: The ?$ was doing the damage in my original example.

Comment: Indeed, presence of `$` makes it match `/tag/` only at the end.